# Page break in .RDLC file after two instance of a group

Tags: rdlc

How can i put two instance of a group on one page in .RDLC file ?
I want to break page after two instance of a group.

It's easy to break after one instance but my requirement is to put two instance of a group and then break the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a `Parent Group` for your initial group in which you specify that the (parent) group is composed by two row of your children group: after that you can easily put the page break, as you know, from the group property.

[I found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10562516/1498857) in SO that explain very well what you have to do with a lot of images. Of course you have to adapt it to your requirement