# Variable number of rows in RDLC Report with Page Breaks

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

First and foremost this is *not* a duplicate of this post: [How to page break after specific row(Suppose 25 rows) in rdlc reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467997/how-to-page-break-after-specific-rowsuppose-25-rows-in-rdlc-reporting) That post solved one part of my question but I am stuck on the second part.

I have a report that represents a cheque.  The report looks (crudely) something like this:

---

Section 1

Make payable to [Dataset field]

Amount: [Dataset field]

Date: [Dataset Field]

---

Section 2

Paid Item 1

Paid Item 2

Paid Item 3

Paid Item 4

---

Section 3

Paid Item 1

Paid Item 2

Paid Item 3

Paid Item 4

---

This report is controlled through a single dataset.

Section 2 and Section 3 is where my problem lies.  These sections represent each row of data inside of the dataset so, if I were to print a cheque right now that had 4 records of data, Sections 2 and 3 would display the same data. This data is contained inside of a List control.

Here is my problem: I need each List Control to display 10 records then print anything beyond 10 records onto a separate page.  When I used the technique described in the SO article above, it works, but when it inserts a page break it also breaks section 3 onto another page.

It seems like I could achieve this through some sort of manipulation of the page breaks but I have not been able to figure it out.  Please let me know if I can be more clear on anything!

Comment: Do you want section 3 to start where section 2 ends. Is this statement correct? Lets say you have 34 paid items then
page 1 -> section 1;
page 2,3,4 -> section 2;
page 5 -> 4 items of section 2 and 6 items of section 3;
page 6,7,8 -> items 7-34 of section 3. 
Is this what you want to achieve or something else?

Comment: Hi Anup.  No.  Section 2 and Section 3 should display exactly the same information.

Comment: Do you want a page break between section 2 & 3?

Comment: Yes.  If the data set contains 15 records, section 2 and section 3 will both display records 1-10 and then the other 5 records would be printed off to another page.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? *but when it inserts a page break it also breaks section 3 onto another page.* To me Page break between groups or even page break before will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is an interesting one and I would offer two parts to my suggestion.

1. You need to make a dataset that has a column that can account for the different sections so you can 'group' by it.  If this does not exist you can create it.
2. You probably need a 'List' item from the Controlbox inside of a tablix report so you can show different column values than under 'Details' section.  SSRS thinks if you are doing grouping your detail and groups will be the same values yet organize differently.  You want different data under section 1 than under section 2 and 3.  For that reason I would use a list item for section 1 to group by what would amount to be it.

You may have issues still with data trying to go for detail under section one as well though.  In the case of this you may have to get clever and do something that takes the logic of the presentation control to another report.  This would be a 'subreport' which you is just basically a different report you may call.  However...  I have not done this with RDLC reports, only RDL HOSTED reports.  I am not certain in an application if you can have one report call other reports.  If this is not possible you may just have to do nesting of objects like a main object be a tablix and the first header gets a list and the others get a nother tablix inside of them.

At that point it may be simpler to just make two tablix objects butt up against each other and one has a filter to only show section one data and the other to anything that does not equal section one.  RDLC reports definitely need some creative thinking at times.