# how to fix the tablix height for SSRS report Detail section

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report which is showing data grouped by one column in the report. The report is working fine but the tablix height is dependent upon the number of lines in the data. I want to fix the height of the tablix so that there are a total of 12 rows in the page. If there are less than 12 rows in the page then rest of the rows will be empty.

I tried this by applying grouping but it disturbed the first grouping that I am using to combine the data in rows.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a rectangle control the layout. Place a rectangle in the report. Make it the height of 12 rows. Then drag the table inside it. Now the table can grow up to 12 rows and anything below the rectangle will not move relative to the table.

Comment: If the report got more that 12 rows then it will expand downward. and we need page break as well after 12 rows. It won't work this way.

Comment: You can certainly add page breaks every 12 rows as well. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467997/how-to-page-break-after-specific-rowsuppose-25-rows-in-rdlc-reporting. I have used this method to build an invoice report before so I know it works. Sometimes it just takes a few tries to work out the kinks.