# How to repeat every page A List and A Table at same time - SSRS

Tags: sql, list, reporting-services

I have a problem. I have a Sql report. And In my report I have a list and then a table. (Image #1)

[image: List And Table]

I set them "Repeat every page." But IF my table data is too long & the data goes to second page, then I can't see the "List" on the second page (Image #2)

[image: Where is my List?]

If my table data has no data then I can see my list on the second page. It works. As I say if my table data is too long then why I can't see my table on the second page?

Comment: Might want to break the table after a specific number of rows. This will force a new page and should the get the list to show again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467997/how-to-page-break-after-specific-rowsuppose-25-rows-in-rdlc-reporting

Comment: Ah cool. That is realy good idea. Thanks a lot.