# How to show a title on each page of the report dynamically created reportviewer

Tags: xml, reportviewer, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I create the report dynamically, i e, I have no way to open a designer RDLC and fix it. I create a table and fill it through the dataset. Getting XML file and export it to PDF file. But even if I write

```
string deviceInfo =
"<DeviceInfo>" +
" <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
" <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
" <PageHeight>8.5.0in</PageHeight>" +
" <MarginTop>0.05in</MarginTop>" +
" <MarginLeft>0.05in</MarginLeft>" +
" <MarginRight>0.05in</MarginRight>" +
" <MarginBottom>0.05in</MarginBottom>" +

" <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>" +
" <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>" + 
" <FixedData>true</FixedData>"+
 " <RepeatHeaderOnNewPage>true</RepeatHeaderOnNewPage>" +
"</DeviceInfo>";
try
{
 byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
 "PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
 out streamids, out warnings);

 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
 {
 fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 fs.Close();
 }
 return filename;
 }
 //....
```

I see the title only on 1 page Help solve the problem! Thanks!

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer ... Please help me!

Comment: Thanks, RoboLover! I am waiting for an answer...

Comment: Np Irena, try to keep your question active by editing and adding new things you found out by your researches, good luck.I hope you can find a solution.

Comment: I added a new node in the rdlc so

Comment: //Add new node
               XmlNode newNode = xDocument.CreateNode("element", "RepeatOnNewPage", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
                newNode.InnerText = "true";
                xDocument.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].AppendChild(newNode); 
But now I get an error
"An error occurred during local report processing"

Comment: Add this part to your question Irena.

Comment: hey Irena check this [dynamic table rdlc](http://gotreportviewer.com/DynamicTable.zip)

Comment: Issue has been resolved! Anyone who read my question - thank you!

Comment: Well, Irena consider answering your own question with the solution you had, for those who may encounter the same problem.

Comment: ok
private Rdl.HeaderType CreateHeader()
{
Rdl.HeaderType header = new Rdl.HeaderType();
header.Items = new object[]
{
 CreateHeaderTableRows(),
true,
};
header.ItemsElementName = new Rdl.ItemsChoiceType20[]
{
Rdl.ItemsChoiceType20.TableRows,
Rdl.ItemsChoiceType20.RepeatOnNewPage,
};
return header;
}

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->
(public string ExportReport(string filename)
{
 Warning[] warnings;
 string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
 string filenameExtension;
string deviceInfo =
"<DeviceInfo>" +
 " <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
" <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
  " <PageHeight>8.5.0in</PageHeight>" +
 " <MarginTop>0.05in</MarginTop>" +
 " <MarginLeft>0.05in</MarginLeft>" +
 " <MarginRight>0.05in</MarginRight>" +
 " <MarginBottom>0.05in</MarginBottom>" +
  "</DeviceInfo>";

Comment: try
 {
byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
 "PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,   //horizontal page
 out streamids, out warnings);
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
 fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 fs.Close();
}
 return filename;
}

Comment: Can you add those as anwer please, Irena? Not comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private Rdl.HeaderType CreateHeader()
    {
        Rdl.HeaderType header = new Rdl.HeaderType();
        header.Items = new object[]
            {
                CreateHeaderTableRows(),
                true,
            };
        header.ItemsElementName = new Rdl.ItemsChoiceType20[]
            {
                Rdl.ItemsChoiceType20.TableRows,
                Rdl.ItemsChoiceType20.RepeatOnNewPage,
            };
        return header;
    }
   //....
    public string ExportReport(string filename)
    {
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
        string deviceInfo =
             "<DeviceInfo>" +
             " <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
             " <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
             " <PageHeight>8.5.0in</PageHeight>" +
             " <MarginTop>0.05in</MarginTop>" +
             " <MarginLeft>0.05in</MarginLeft>" +
             " <MarginRight>0.05in</MarginRight>" +
             " <MarginBottom>0.05in</MarginBottom>" +
             "</DeviceInfo>"; 
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
                "PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,                       out streamids, out warnings);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
            return filename;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Program.WriteLogEx.WriterLogErr(e.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }
```